# One computer can connect, the other no

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ssh, nas

I have two laptops, both with windows 10 pro and connected to the same wireless network. And also, a NAS which is accessible via the same network. One laptop can access the NAS over HTTP and SSH and the cannot. I get connection time out error.
Can someone help me diagnose this problem and eventually solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Update: I forgot to mention that the laptop who is not connecting was connecting some days ago.

Comment: Make sure the computers are set the same way: Network Discovery, F/P Sharing, Password protected sharing ON and Wireless set to Private.

Comment: Has anything changed?  Can you reset the wireless network?

Comment: Hi @John, I just check the wireless settings in both laptops. The only differences are the protocol (802.11n vs 802.11ac) and the Network Channel (11 vs 36). I don't know how to change any of those.

Comment: Hi @StainlessSteelRat, What do you mean resetting the network? In AP or laptop?

Answer (score 0):

My bad,

I appears my NAS was blocking my Ip Address